# Fullpage JS - Fullscreen slider with mini slider inside

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am trying to replicate http://www.apple.com/iphone/why-theres-iphone/ with FullPage Slider. The main background slide is pretty straight forward. Now I need to get the Phone part to slide as well.

My page so far: http://scram.rambo.co.za/

I have code thus far looking something like this:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
    </div>
</div>

<figure class="iphone">
    <div class="iphone-device">
        <div class="iphone-content-wrapper">
            <div class="phone-screen screen1">
                <div class="screen-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="phone-screen screen2">
                <div class="screen-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="phone-screen screen3">
                <div class="screen-wrapper"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</figure>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        'verticalCentered': false,
        'css3': true,
        'navigation': true,
        'navigationPosition': 'left'
    });
});
</script>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the callbacks fullpage.js provides (onLeave, afterLoad) or the state class `fp-viewing-X-Y` added on the `body` to perform the animations on the phone.

Look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M&spfreload=10) for more info.